# Issue while running JUnit with getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate() method in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, dao

I am trying to implement JUnit for the DAO classes in my Spring Batch project.
Since i do not want a access the database directly i am overriding the methods for jdbctemplate class in my JUnit.

Below is the example of a DAO class and the JUnit code that i am using

DAO classes:

class `transDaoJdbcImpl`

```
public class transDaoJdbcImpl extends jdbcAbstractDao {

    public tranVo fetchHistory(Integer feedFileId) {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> binding = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            binding.put("ID", "value");

            return super.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
                    this.sSQL,
                    binding,
                    new testMapper());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printstacktrace();
        }
    }

}

class DistbatchAbstractDao {
    public abstract class DistbatchAbstractDao extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport {
    protected int update(String sql, Map<String, ?> paramMap) throws Exception {
        try {
            return getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(sql, paramMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("update() error:\n" + e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    ........
    other methods

}
```

JUnit code:

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = 
    new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(Mockito.mock(DataSource.class)) {

    @Override
    public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, Map<String, ?> paramMap, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)
            throws Exception {

        return null;
    }
};
transDaoJdbcImpl() dao = new transDaoJdbcImpl() {
    @Override
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate() {

        return template;
    }
};
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(dao, "SQLName", sql);
dao.fetchHistory(1099999);
```

when I run the `JUnit` the `fetchHistory()` in the transDaoJdbcImpl file.
and since I do a `super.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().queryForObject` the super class method of the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` is getting called.
I don't want that but I want the `getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate()` which I have overridden in my `JUnit` to be called as I am overriding the functionality.
Currently this is not happening and `getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate()` is always null in the `fetchHistory()`.
Can anyone let me know how I can do that and what is the problem with my code above.
any help would be great as I am stuck on this for a long time now.

Thanks

Vikeng21

Answer (score 3):

So here is the solution that worked for me. since its a peculiar question case and i did not get any comments or answers on this from anyone thought the solution that worked for me can also help anyone who faces the same issues in the future.

**Soution: JUnit code**

```
private transDaoJdbcImpl dao;
/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    dao=new transDaoJdbcImpl ();
    tranVo vo=new tranVo ();
    vo.setId(1);
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateMock = Mockito.mock(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.class);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(dao, "namedParameterJdbcTemplate", jdbcTemplateMock);
    Mockito.when(jdbcTemplateMock.queryForObject(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyMap() ,Mockito.any(RowMapper.class))).thenReturn(vo);
}


@Test
public void testFetchHistory() {
    tranVo vo=dao.retrieveLatestHistory(1);

    Assert.assertEquals("TEST",vo.getCd());
}
```

Comment: Good answer,helped me a lot

Comment: Was struggling to mock `NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport`'s `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. Thanks.